# Appium waitForElementByName always returns state: pending

Tags: webdriver, appium

So I'm using [Appium](http://appium.io/) to test an iOS app. I've written my tests in javascript and am using Mocha as the testing framework. Everything runs fine except for trying to get an example test to pass:

```
it('should find sign up label', function () {
  return driver.waitForElementByName('_signUpLabel', 3000)
    .then(function (el) {
      el.text().should.equal('Sign up with...');
    });
});
```

And this is the app's code in question:

```
_signUpLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init];
[_signUpLabel setAccessibilityIdentifier:@"_signUpLabel"];
...
[_signUpLabel setText:@"Sign up with..."];
[view addSubview:_signUpLabel];
```

The iOS simulator loads, then the app loads, then the login view loads just fine with the element in view, yet the error I receive is: `AssertionError: expected { state: 'pending' } to equal 'Sign up with...'`

I can see that Appium has found *an* element through its logging:

```
 > CALL waitForElementByName("_signUpLabel",3000)
 > CALL elements("name","_signUpLabel")
 > POST /session/:sessionID/elements {"using":"name","value":"_signUpLabel"}
 > RESPONSE elements("name","_signUpLabel") [{"ELEMENT":"0"}]
 > RESPONSE waitForElementByName("_signUpLabel",3000) {"ELEMENT":"0"}
 > CALL element.text()
 > GET /session/:sessionID/element/0/text
```

So can someone tell me where I'm being stupid?

Comment: Did you ever solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Is `el.text()` sync or async? The `pending` suggests you might need to wait for a result?

Comment: Sure, that's correct but _how_? It doesn't return a promise so what do I do?